# How tight does the oil filler cap need to be?

Tags: oil

1999 Civic coupe vti.

So it does not come off or conversely strip, how tight does the oil filler cap need to be, hand tight or a lot more?

Thanks

Comment: It would help it you told us which vehicle the oil filler cap is fitted to, if indeed it is a vehicle.  Also is it the oil filler cap for an engine?

Answer (score 0):

Depends, some have a coarse thread, some have a ramp and spring clip.

If it is a thread then reasonably tight or sufficiently tight. Never will you need to use a spanner or adjustable wrench to do it up.

The ramp and clip type are self setting.

Comment: How much tighter is reasonably tight or sufficiently tight from hand tight?